# Pom.xml returns error in compiling maven-processor-plugin

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm trying to build a jhipster project.
I am trying to set up a local server and run a hello world kind of application.
My pom.xml file is the following:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                    <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <defaultOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</defaultOutputDirectory>
                <processors>
                    <processor>org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor</processor>
                </processors>
                <options>
                    <mapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp>true</mapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp>
                    <mapstruct.defaultComponentModel>spring</mapstruct.defaultComponentModel>
                </options>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The error I get during the maven build process is the following:

```
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:2.2.4:process (process) on project jhipsterdemo: Error executing
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error executing
at org.bsc.maven.plugin.processor.AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.execute(AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.java:292)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: error during compilation
at org.bsc.maven.plugin.processor.AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.executeWithExceptionsHandled(AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.java:548)
at org.bsc.maven.plugin.processor.AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.execute(AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.java:285)
... 22 more
```

I am a beginner and am unable to find the source of the error. I haven't modified any code and so expect the build process to run.
Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: From where are you running your maven project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix issue with **maven-processor-plugin:2.2.4:process** plugin in Eclipse.

Follow this [Jhipster Import Process](https://jhipster.github.io/configuring-ide-eclipse/).

Also you can simply go to the root directory of your application where `pom.xml` exists in command prompt and then run :

```
mvn
```

And in another command prompt window run:

```
gulp
```

`mvn` will fetch all pom dependencies, compile and start your application (@port 8080)

`gulp` will fetch all JavaScript, CSS, etc dependencies and wire up your front-end angular code and start your application in browser (@port 9000).